# Haskell: Using cabal-dev with local packages over Hackage

Tags: haskell, cabal, yesod, cabal-dev

I'm trying to install a yesod web application, however, one of the listed dependencies has compile-time errors as-is from Hackage. So, I downloaded the offending source, fixed it, and installed it in its own cabal-dev sandbox.

```
~/dev/fixed_dep$ cabal-dev install
```

Then I tried to install the yesod app I care about on top of that, so it would hopefully notice the fixed dependency and not try to reinstall it from Hackage:

```
~/dev/yesod_app$ cabal-dev install-deps -s../dev/fixed-dep/cabal-dev
~/dev/yesod_app$ yesod --dev devel
```

However, upon running the development server, it claims it can't find *any* of the dependencies.

Any ideas how to fix this mess? (*)

Thanks!

(*) I pushed the compile-error patch to the author's github and I imagine it will show up sooner or later on Hackage, however, I'd like to know how to fix this cabal-dev issue regardless, if it's possible!

Comment: In the source directory for the yesod package you desire, you can add the fixed dependency via `cabal-dev add-source path-to-cabalized-fixed-dependency`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Thomas M. DuBuisson, this did the trick:

```
~/dev/yesod_app$ cabal-dev add-source ~/dev/the_dependency_folder
```

Where the_dependency_folder contains the .cabal file of the fixed local package to include with the main Yesod web app's cabal-dev install.